# AMaViS: missing X-Spam-Status header

Tags: debian, email-server, debian-squeeze, spamassassin, amavis

I set up a mail server with Dovecot, Postfix and AMaViS on Debian Squeeze following the tutorial on [workaround.org (ISPmail tutorial for Debian Squeeze)](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze). It uses virtual domains and stores the domains, e-mail addresses and accounts in a MySQL database.

Everything works fine – except I am missing some e-mail headers.

### Received headers:

- X-Quarantine-ID
- X-Virus-Scanned

(With “real” spam and using the GTUBE via `sendmail email@example.com < /usr/share/doc/spamassassin/examples/sample-spam.txt`)

### Missing headers:

- X-Spam-Flag
- X-Spam-Score
- X-Spam-Level
- X-Spam-Status

**But** spam e-mails get their subject changed. So I set up everything correct, didn’t I?

How do I get those missing headers in my mails?

---

Here my AMaViS configuration file (`/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`)

```
use strict;

#
# Place your configuration directives here.  They will override those in
# earlier files.
#
# See /usr/share/doc/amavisd-new/ for documentation and examples of
# the directives you can use in this file
#

# see <http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze/content-scanning-amavis>

$sa_spam_subject_tag = '*** SPAM *** ';
$final_spam_destiny = D_PASS;

$sa_tag_level_deflt = -9999; # add spam info headers if at, or above that level
$sa_tag2_level_deflt = 6.31; # add 'spam detected' headers at that level


@lookup_sql_dsn = ([
    'DBI:mysql:database=mailserver;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306',
    'mailuser',
    'password'
]);

$sql_select_policy = 'SELECT name FROM virtual_domains WHERE CONCAT("@",name) IN (%k)';

#------------ Do not modify anything below this line -------------
1;  # ensure a defined return
```

If you need more configuration files, log outputs or anything else, please leave a comment below and I will update my post with the information you need :-)

Answer (score 19):

Have you checked this parameter: @local_domains_acl

It is defined on `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`. According to the Amavisd-new documentation on http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/ :

> No spam-related headers inserted? Here are some reasons:
>
> - @local_domains_acl is not correctly set. These headers are only inserted for recipients matching @local_domains_acl lookup (or
>   %local_domains or $local_domains_re or field 'local' in SQL lookups);
> - (...)

Check the output of this command: `head -n 1 /etc/mailname`

If you will not get exactly your domain name than Amavisd will not apply any change to the headers of your emails. If you want to force the adding of the X-Spam-* headers than you can add something like this `@local_domains_acl = ( "." );` on `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`

Answer (score 6):

(This is really a comment to the previous answer, but the reputation system won't let me)

Setting `@local_domains_acl = ( "." )` worked for me, but it seemed like a rather blunt instrument (i.e., spam processing all messages, in or out).  Trying a number of alternatives, I eventually found that including `localhost` would also help (I'm testing with a delivery service on the same box).  Thus, in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user` I have something like:

```
@local_domains_acl = ( ".mydomain.example.org", "localhost" );
```

and I'm seeing messages delivered with spam headers added.

(My test setup here is Ubuntu 14.04 server, postfix, amaviz, spamassassin, all installed from standard Ubuntu repositories.)

Answer (score 4):

The output of command `head -n 1 /etc/mailname` must be your domain, like `example.com`.

If the output is something like `mail.example.com`, **that's the bug**.

So, you can fix this by changing the file `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`

**Solution #1**

Inside `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`:

Change:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `head -n 1 /etc/mailname`);
```

To:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `hostname -d`);
```

PS: The output of `hostname -d` must be your domain, like `example.com`.

**Solution #2**

Inside `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`:

Change:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `head -n 1 /etc/mailname`);
```

To:

```
    $mydomain = "example.com";
```